# Not able to cd into samba location (in a windows share location)

Tags: server, windows, samba

I am not able to `cd` into the samba like I would normally do:

```
cd smb://server/folder
```

It says: `"bash: cd: smb/..." No such file or directory.`

But if in nautilus I go to the folder and right click it, the location shown in the properties is:

```
smb://server/folder
```

Why isn't this working?
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The program "cd" can only navigate into directories mounted to your local VFS, and a URI that starts with "smb://" describes a remote resource.  In order to cd into an SMB share, you have to mount it.

In your case, it sounds like the SMB share was already mounted and accessible from nautilus.  That means the SMB share is already mounted somewhere in your local VFS.

In Ubuntu 15.04, I believe the default mount point for SMB shares (at least the ones you connect to using nautilus) is:

```
/run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb:host=$SERVER_NAME
```

So instead, try:

```
$ cd  /run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb:host=server/path/to/file.txt
```

Edit: For a more in-depth explanation of this, here is [a similar question on unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/nautilus-special-uris) with some great answers

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22 and my gvfs directory is empty, despite having several Samba shares.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use just `cd smb://server/folder` from a terminal.

To access the folder from terminal you need to `mount` the folder first.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/server

sudo mount -t cifs //remote/folder /mnt/server -o username=user uid=name
```

Or just type `smbclient //hostname/folder` and type the username/password. After successful login you will able to access the folders.

Comment: how do I set up to automount it with fstab? Currently looks like: smb://folder /media/folder nfts defaults 0 0; It says Failed to access volume, no such file or folder. But I got the "smb://folder" path from the automatically mounted in the network list.

Comment: I would recommend you to use autofs instead of fstab. Please refer this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) to automount.

Comment: mount.cifs doesn't use URLs, but UNCs - you would use //remote/folder rather than smb://remote/folder

Comment: Yes I have mentioned that smb:://remote/folder wont work

Answer (score 1):

The shell (bash) does not use unique resource locators (URLs).

In addition to other answers that tell you how to mount samba shares manually, if you can access it with the file manager, it has already been mounted using gvfs. You will be able to access it throught the `.gvfs/` directory in your home directory:

```
cd ~/.gvfs/
ls
```

If I'm correct, you should see a directory called `folder on server/`.

Answer (score 0):

The smb protocol cannot be used like this from `bash`. If you want to use it, you have to mount the smb share with the `mount` command, or to add it to your `/etc/fstab`, for example (taken from my fstab):

```
//server/smb-share /my/path/where/to/mount/it cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the others don't work (as is my case), you'll likely find this will:

`cd /$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/smb-share\:server=yourserver,share=yourshare/`

Replace `yourserver` and `yourshare` appropriately.

If you're using tab completion, beware of your shell incorrectly escaping out commas, dollar symbols and slashes. The colon, however, *should* be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

go to 'files' folder (left panel) in ubuntu, open shared folder ....^  .Then rightclik and select 'open in Terminal' >> copy address like bellow in front of your cd command

cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xxx.xxx.x.xxx,share=[your shared folder in other system]

Comment: This answer needs some supporting details.