# Samba share points not visible in google Chrome "save as" utility in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, samba

I generally mount 2 NAS with nautilus as samba shares. I mount them manually with nautilus.

For some unknown reason I cannot see those shares anymore when I want to "save as" a file on one of those 2 NAS.

Any idea ?

Please look at the picture that the samba share points do not appear

[image]

Comment: Likely a dumb question but did you run sudo service samba status?

Answer (score -1):

Regarding my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/923428/631600):

Nautilus uses [gvfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs) to mount samba shares. Find out where it is located in your file system using this command:

```
mount | grep gvfs
```

Assuming you use the default Ubuntu configuration and are the first (or only) user on your Ubuntu machine, the mount point of already mounted Shares from Nautilus is  below this folder:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/
```

With the `1000` being your User ID. 1000 is the default UID for the first user of the system. Find out your User ID with the following command:

```
id -u
```

Go to `Ordinateur` to find `/run` folder.

Comment: the mont | grep gvfs gives me mount | grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=laurent06000) but my problem is that before I could see my mounted shares close to ordinateur and they disapeared

Comment: I can save my files following the /run/user/1000/gvfs/"share point" but the other way was far much convenient